# using Rayleigh's Quotient to determine the interval along which $\lambda$ lies to avoid considering all possible cases of $\lambda$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have heard in my lectures that When solving for a PDE using the separation of variables, one check for all possible cases of $$\text{$\lambda >$0,$\lambda $=0,$\lambda <$0}$$, but this process can be narrowed down using theorems in Sturm-Liouville.

Is it the Rayleigh's Quotient that enables one to narrow down to the specific case of $\lambda$?

An example would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Rayleigh's quotient can be used, but it would be for specific PDE, since it relates to the Laplace/ Dirichlet eigenvalue problem, $-\Delta u = 0$, $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Take for example the heat equation $\partial_tu-\Delta u$, let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, plug it into the equation and you find that $$-\Delta X=\lambda X,$$ and $$T'(t)=-\lambda T.$$
When solving $-\Delta X=\lambda X$, we know that the minimum eigenvalue is given by Rayleigh's quotient i.e., $$\lambda_1=\min_{u\in V}\frac{\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\,dx}{\int_\Omega u^2\,dx},$$
where $V=\{v\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega}):u|_{\partial\Omega=0}\}.$
The smallest eigenvalue is non negative, so this rules out non negative values of $\lambda$.